# openWRT Dropbear SSH key authentication fails with "unknown algo"

Tags: linux, ssh, openwrt, dropbear

Good day, I'm trying to figure out how to get a user to ssh into openWRT with only a key.
I followed these instructions:
 https://wiki.openwrt.org/oldwiki/dropbearpublickeyauthenticationhowto.

In short:
On a Linux box:
 If you haven't already got a

```
.ssh/id_dsa.pub
ssh-keygen -t dsa
scp ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub root@192.168.1.1:/tmp
```

On openWRT:

```
cd /etc/dropbear
cat /tmp/id_*.pub >> authorized_keys
chmod 0600 authorized_keys
```

When I try and ssh in, I get this error:

> authpriv.warn dropbear[2085]: Pubkey auth attempt with unknown algo for 'MyUser' from 1.2.3.4:11111

I have tried generating a RSA key too, same result.
I can log in as the user using a password:

> authpriv.notice dropbear[2089]: Password auth succeeded for 'MyUser' from 1.2.3.4:11111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's the problem of the OpenWRT version. 
Try `${HOME}/.ssh/authorized_keys` instead.

Comment: Yes, spot on! Thx!

Comment: That solved it for me also, using a 2019 Buildroot image.  I also had to add `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa` to my Host definition on my client side, because recent openssh refuses to use RSA signed keys (use `ssh -vvv` and look for the "no mutual signature algorithm" debug message).